# Getting an error while running password change script

Tags: php

I have a form to change the password of user. It takes the input on profile page and then sends to another page for processing. But i am getting the error login_failed even if i am leaving any of the field blnk. In blank case, the error should be Fill all the fields. Can someone tell where is the problem.

```
<form method="post" action="updatepassword.php">
           <input name="pass" type="text" placeholder="Old password" /> 
           <input name="pass1" type="text" placeholder="New password" /> 
           <input name="pass2" type="text" placeholder="Confirm password" />
                      <input id="butt" type="submit" value="Update" name="pinchange"> 
                      </form>
```

updatepassword.php

```
<?php
include_once("login_status.php");

}

if(isset($_POST['pinchange']))
{
 $pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
 $pass1=md5($_POST['pass1']);
 $pass2=md5($_POST['pass2']);
 if($pass==""||$pass1==""||$pass2==""){ echo "Fill all the fields"; exit();}
 else{
 $sql = "SELECT id,password FROM users WHERE username='$log_username' ;
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_pass_str = $row[1];
        if($pass != $db_pass_str){      
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: What happens if the username is wrong?

Comment: Don't use md5, please don't. just don't. really, trusy me. don't. MD5 was never designed for password hasing.

Comment: @Pinoniq can you explain why not to use md5..??

Comment: google my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords md5 is an algorithm designed for speed. not security

Comment: @Pinoniq: I kow this too my friend that it is not safe for hashing. I am working on a dummy project. But i am about to complete it and now my worry is the hashing technique. I searched alot for this but still no good tutorial found. Everyone tells how to change using  different techniques but no one tells how to authenticate.

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario : I am including the login_status.php in beginning which will provide the username.

Comment: Pardon? You only have one username and it's hard-coded?

Comment: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMPORTANT NOTE: it is considered very bad practice to use MD5 for storing and retrieving passwords. This answer just shows what was wrong with the code. It does not encourage the use of MD5 hashing at all.**

You should only convert the passwords with `md5` **after** you compare them to empty strings. So you should do:

```
<?php
include_once("login_status.php");

if(isset($_POST['pinchange']))
{
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 $pass1=$_POST['pass1'];
 $pass2=$_POST['pass2'];
 if($pass==""||$pass1==""||$pass2==""){ echo "Fill all the fields"; exit();}
 else{
     $sql = "SELECT id,password FROM users WHERE username='$log_username'" ;
     $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
     $db_id = $row[0];
     $db_pass_str = $row[1];
     if(md5($pass) != $db_pass_str){      
         echo "login_failed";
         exit();
     }
}
```

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use md5 for passwords. Ever.

Comment: Absolutely true, but it does pinpoint the problem at hand here.

Comment: @lowerends: Thanks alot.. it worked. One more question to ask. Right know,in cae of errors it is showing in a blank pge. I want to show it just below the form near submit button. i know it could be done using JavaScript but really dont know how. Any suggestion on it.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for that tagged with PHP and Javascript. That will give you the best chance for a good answer.

Comment: Here is my final code with JavaScript. If i am supplying all the fields correctly, then please wait is coming but no further response is being received..what should i do here?

Comment: I would have upvoted this, but not mentioning the fact that the OP stands at eventually getting hacked using a hashing method that is considered broken, and not giving proper guidance, is why. I no longer give "answers" related to MD5 password storage methods; not without adding an alternate and safer method as well as using prepared statements; it's just a question of "time".

Comment: @Fred -ii- I've added an explicit note to the top of my answer to make it clear to anybody reading this answer and not the comments that MD5 should not be used.

Comment: It's always best to do so. Should you encounter more questions involving MD5 or any other unsafe hashing method, you could tell them to use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). ;-)